# How do I place a redirect before a compound command in bash?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I was sad to find out that bash (and most other sh-derived shells) interpret sequences of redirects backwards,
with respect to the logical grouping.
E.g. to run my_command with file descriptors 1 (stdout) and 2 (stderr) swapped, I have to say:

```
my_command 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
```

which does *not* mean:

```
{ { { my_command 3>&1; } 1>&2; } 2>&3; } 3>&-
```

Instead, it means:

```
{ { { my_command 3>&-; } 2>&3; } 1>&2; } 3>&1
```

This backwards interpretation is always an annoying speedbump for me when I'm trying to make sense of a sequence of redirects.

But then, I was happy to find out that I can put the redirects *before* the command:

```
3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- my_command
```

which *does* mean the same thing as the following (if only the following were legal):

```
3>&1 { 1>&2 { 2>&3 { 3>&- my_command; }; }; }
```

Hooray!  So I was thinking, maybe I'll start putting all my redirects before my commands,
so that the order will agree with the logical grouping.

But then I was sad again, to find that `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- my_command`
is legal only when `my_command` is a simple command, not when it's a compound command (i.e. delimited by `{}`),
and not even when it's an *alias* for a compound command.

For example, I'd like to say the following, but it doesn't work:

```
3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- { echo to stdout; echo to stderr >&2; } | cat -n
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

The desired output is:

```
to stdout
  1      to stderr
```

I can think of the following workarounds; these all work correctly,
but none of them really satisfy my wish, which is to express the logical grouping clearly.

**Workaround #1:** give in, and put the redirects after the command:

```
{ echo to stdout; echo to stderr >&2; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | cat -n
```

**Workaround #2:** use `exec`

```
{ exec 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- && { echo to stdout; echo to stderr >&2; }; } | cat -n
```

**Workaround #3:** fork an explicit subshell, thereby avoiding a compound command:

```
3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- sh -c 'echo to stdout; echo to stderr >&2' | cat -n
```

**Workaround #4:** wrap the command in a function (not an alias):

```
function my_command() { echo to stdout; echo to stderr >&2; }
3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- my_command | cat -n
```

Is there some nicer syntax I'm missing, that will let me place a redirect before a compound command in bash?
Or are these two features that simply don't work together?

Comment: Note: What you call "backwards interpretation" I call "natural". POSIX states [`If more than one redirection operator is specified with a command, the order of evaluation is from beginning to end`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07). My intuition comes from reading: from beginning to end. Your intuition obviously comes from elsewhere. Can you tell the origin of it? I'm just curious; I'm not a programmer and I cannot guess.

Comment: Hi @KamilMaciorowski , sure.   Maybe the simplest example: I'd expect 
`echo hello 1>&2 2>&1` to mean the same as `{ echo hello 1>&2; } 2>&1` ,
but it doesn't; it means `{ echo hello 2>&1; } 1>&2` instead.
Don't you think that's at least a *little* bit backwards?

Comment: I got confused: which one is backwards? `echo hello 1>&2 2>&1`? or `{ echo hello 2>&1; } 1>&2`? From the question I got the impression you think `my_command 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-` works backwards, so you would probably say `echo hello 1>&2 2>&1` works backwards as well. My point is: in this simplest form redirections work "naturally": from beginning to end, from left to right. Your comment doesn't shed any light on why one would expect it to work in any other way (this was the gist of my comment). But if you think `{ echo hello 2>&1; } 1>&2` works in an unexpected way, I may carefully agree.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Correct, I'm saying that how bash interpets `echo hello 1>&2 2>&1` (i.e. "direct both streams to the original 2") seems backwards to me because it's the opposite of what `{ echo hello 1>&2; } 2>&1` means ("direct both streams to the original 1"). The latter expression is uncontroversial; it couldn't possibly mean anything else (think of the curly-braced subexpression as simply a black-box program that emits something to its fd 2, in whatever way it wants to implement that), so I'm saying the former expression is the backwards one.